# Redis SYNC and EXEC

Tags: database, redis, nosql, pipeline, jedis

Redis pipeline has 2 options to send commands to database "exec" and "sync". I'd want to know what is the difference between them.

I'll use Jedis ,java api for redis, for the examples.

**Examples**

Example 1

```
try (Jedis resource = redisManager.getResource()) {
    Pipeline pipeline = resource.pipelined();
    pipeline.multi();

    pipeline.del("test-1");
    pipeline.hset("test-2", "a", "b");

    pipeline.exec();
}
```

Example 2

```
try (Jedis resource = redisManager.getResource()) {
    Pipeline pipeline = resource.pipelined();
    pipeline.multi();

    pipeline.del("test-1");
    pipeline.hset("test-2", "a", "b");

    pipeline.sync();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pipeline execute method returns

`Response<List<?>>`

whereas sync returns **void**, however, to get response from pipeline using sync you have to capture individual responses, something like this.

```
Response<Long> isDeleted = pipeline.del("test-1");
Response<Long> isSuccess = pipeline.hset("test-2", "a", "b");
Response<List<String>> hvals = pipeline.hvals("test-2");
pipeline.sync();
assertEquals(1, (long) isDeleted.get());
```