# How to delete a list of keys in Redis using Java/Spring APIs and return whether all keys delete or not?

Tags: java, spring, redis

I have a logic which needs to delete a list of keys in Redis cache and I want to know whether all keys are deleted or not (if all of them deleted successfully, I want to get result "true", but if some of them are not deleted successfully, I want to get result "false").

I'm wondering are there any relatively easy workaround for such a logic with java/spring apis? thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

redis **DEL** command returns number of keys deleted.

You can pass small batches such as 100 keys per **DEL** call and count the return value to be exact of the batch size.

Comment: what if I want to do batch operations of not only `delete`, but different operations like including modify, delete, add, and I only want to know whether all of these operations succeed or not?

Comment: all redis commands return the status of the command this way you can use pipeline and check the status of each command.

Comment: but pipeline in RedisTemplate doesn't return the results of running the commands, and it seems not possible to check the status of each command in pipeline.

Comment: I'm not aware of RedisTempate, however you can achieve this with Jedis see the answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61692893/redis-sync-and-exec/61694032#61694032